# Is the extensionality axiom constructive?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I'm working in ZFC and wondering which axioms can be considered constructive. I find Axioms of Pair, Union, Empty Set, Infinite, Power Set and Replacement to be clearly constuctive. Choice and Regularity/Foundation are non-constructive.

I've read [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/axioms-CZF-IZF.html) that constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel considers Extensionality. How is Extensionality constructive?

Comment: Extensionality is obviously not constructive, but the goal of "Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel" is not to have a theory with only constructive axioms, it's to have a theory that avoids non-constructive axioms.

Comment: @jjagmath I don't understand your comment at all. Why is extensionality obviously not constructive? What is the difference between having only constructive axioms and avoiding non-constructive axioms? Is it a joke about double negation?

Comment: Extensionality doesn't stablish the existence of a set. That's why it's neither constructive nor non-constructive. The axioms that talk about the existence of a set are the ones that you can classify as constructive or non-constructive.

Comment: And it's not a joke about double negation. It's just that constructive and non-constructive doesn't exhaust the whole range of axioms. Just like prime and composite numbers doesn't exhaust all the integers: $1$ is neither. Another example: the residues modulo $5$ are $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. $1$ and $4$ are quadratic residues, $2$ and $3$ are non-quadratic residues, $0$ is neither.

Comment: [Constructive and intuitionistic Zermelo-Fraenkel set theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/index.html#EssConIntSetThe) are based on intuitionistic rather than classical logic, and represent a natural environment within which to codify and study mathematics based on intuitionistic logic. So, per comments above, the "restrictions" are those of intuitionistic logic regarding the use of LEM with infinite collections and the existence proofs.